# Java is Crashing When Trying to Start Cassandra

Tags: java, windows, cassandra

I am working on Windows 10 and I just installed Cassandra yesterday.  Now, I navigate to the bin folder than enter Cassandra, like this.

```
C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\bin>cassandra
```

I have `jdk-14.0.2` and `jre1.8.0_261`.  I created a variable named `'JAVA_HOME'` and pointed this to the jre folder.

I'm getting a weird error which I don't understand.  Here is the stack trace of my error:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\bin>cassandra
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\conf\jvm.options' because it does not
exist.
At C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:304 char:16
+     $content = Get-Content "$env:CASSANDRA_CONF\jvm.options"
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...onf\jvm.options:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/SerializationHelper;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/net/FrameDecoderWith8bHeader.decode (Ljava/util/Collection;Lorg/apache/cassandra/net/ShareableBytes;I)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/service/reads/repair/RowIteratorMergeListener.applyToPartition (ILjava/util/function/Consumer;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/memory/BufferPool$LocalPool.tryGetInternal (IZ)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeUnsignedVInt (JI)[B
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeUnsignedVInt (JI[B)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.writeUnsignedVInt (JLjava/io/DataOutput;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.writeUnsignedVInt (JLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.writeVInt (JLjava/io/DataOutput;)V

C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\bin>INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,262 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,340 Config.java:662 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor=null; audit_logging_options=AuditLogOptions{enabled=false, logger='BinAuditLogger', included_keyspaces='', excluded_keyspaces='system,system_schema,system_virtual_schema', included_categories='', excluded_categories='', included_users='', excluded_users='', audit_logs_dir='C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\logs/audit/', archive_command='', roll_cycle='HOURLY', block=true, max_queue_weight=268435456, max_log_size=17179869184}; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; autocompaction_on_startup_enabled=true; automatic_sstable_upgrade=false; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=null; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; block_for_peers_in_remote_dcs=false; block_for_peers_timeout_in_secs=10; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=false; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_group_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=64; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_builders=1; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_validations=0; concurrent_writes=32; corrupted_tombstone_strategy=disabled; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=true; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@175c2241; diagnostic_events_enabled=false; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=false; enable_sasi_indexes=false; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_transient_replication=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; flush_compression=fast; full_query_logging_options=FullQueryLoggerOptions{log_dir='', archive_command='', roll_cycle='HOURLY', block=true, max_queue_weight=268435456, max_log_size=17179869184}; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; ideal_consistency_level=null; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_range_tombstone_list_allocation_size=1; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_application_receive_queue_capacity_in_bytes=4194304; internode_application_receive_queue_reserve_endpoint_capacity_in_bytes=134217728; internode_application_receive_queue_reserve_global_capacity_in_bytes=536870912; internode_application_send_queue_capacity_in_bytes=4194304; internode_application_send_queue_reserve_endpoint_capacity_in_bytes=134217728; internode_application_send_queue_reserve_global_capacity_in_bytes=536870912; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_max_message_size_in_bytes=null; internode_socket_receive_buffer_size_in_bytes=0; internode_socket_send_buffer_size_in_bytes=0; internode_tcp_connect_timeout_in_ms=2000; internode_tcp_user_timeout_in_ms=30000; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_migrate_during_compaction=true; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_concurrent_automatic_sstable_upgrades=1; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_allow_older_protocols=true; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=false; native_transport_frame_block_size_in_kb=32; native_transport_idle_timeout_in_ms=0; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=null; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; network_authorizer=AllowAllNetworkAuthorizer; num_tokens=256; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; periodic_commitlog_sync_lag_block_in_ms=null; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; range_tombstone_list_growth_factor=1.5; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_command_pool_full_strategy=queue; repair_command_pool_size=0; repair_session_max_tree_depth=null; repair_session_space_in_mb=null; repaired_data_tracking_for_partition_reads_enabled=false; repaired_data_tracking_for_range_reads_enabled=false; report_unconfirmed_repaired_data_mismatches=false; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1:7000}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; snapshot_on_repaired_data_mismatch=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; storage_port=7000; stream_entire_sstables=true; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_connections_per_host=1; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@5bf0d49; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; use_offheap_merkle_trees=true; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; validation_preview_purge_head_start_in_sec=3600; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,341 DatabaseDescriptor.java:414 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,343 DatabaseDescriptor.java:472 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 490MB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,344 DatabaseDescriptor.java:476 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 490MB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,763 JMXServerUtils.java:262 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,769 CassandraDaemon.java:511 - Hostname: LAPTOP-CEDUMII6:7000:7001
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,769 CassandraDaemon.java:518 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_261
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,770 CassandraDaemon.java:519 - Heap size: 1.917GiB/1.917GiB
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,771 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 4239616(4140K) committed = 4259840(4160K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,771 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 20578656(20096K) committed = 21233664(20736K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,771 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2503176(2444K) committed = 2621440(2560K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,772 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - PS Eden Space Heap memory: init = 537395200(524800K) used = 139731456(136456K) committed = 537395200(524800K) max = 537395200(524800K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,772 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - PS Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 89128960(87040K) used = 0(0K) committed = 89128960(87040K) max = 89128960(87040K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,772 CassandraDaemon.java:524 - PS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 1431830528(1398272K) used = 0(0K) committed = 1431830528(1398272K) max = 1431830528(1398272K)
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,772 CassandraDaemon.java:526 - Classpath: C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\conf;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/airline-0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/asm-7.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/caffeine-2.3.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.9.0-shaded.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/chronicle-bytes-1.16.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/chronicle-core-1.16.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/chronicle-queue-4.16.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/chronicle-threads-1.16.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/chronicle-wire-1.16.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/ecj-4.6.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/guava-27.0-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/hppc-0.8.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jackson-core-2.9.10.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.10.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jamm-0.3.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/javax.inject.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jcommander-1.30.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jflex-1.6.0.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/jvm-attach-api-1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/mxdump-0.14.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.31.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/ohc-core-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/psjava-0.1.19.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/sjk-cli-0.14.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/sjk-core-0.14.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/sjk-json-0.14.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/sjk-stacktrace-0.14.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar;C:/Program Files/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1/lib/zstd-jni-1.3.8-5.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\build\classes\main;C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\lib\jamm-0.3.2.jar
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,774 CassandraDaemon.java:528 - JVM Arguments: [-Dcassandra, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\data, -Xloggc:C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\/logs/gc.log, -Xms2048M, -Xmx2048M, -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\lib\sigar-bin, -XX:CompileCommandFile=C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\conf\hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\\lib\jamm-0.3.2.jar, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199]
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,833 MonotonicClock.java:199 - Scheduling approximate time conversion task with an interval of 10000 milliseconds
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,835 MonotonicClock.java:335 - Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 2 milliseconds
WARN  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,836 StartupChecks.java:182 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2020-07-28 08:39:12,838 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=8032, tid=0x0000000000004c50
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1\bin\hs_err_pid8032.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

This is my first time trying to setup and run Cassandra.  I don't know what the issue is, but I feel like it has something to do with a configuration setting, or maybe a permission issue.  I followed the tutorial from this link.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1waKtjNt88

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the `jvm.options` file.  Also, Cassandra 4.0 has been tested on Java 9 and 11.  It should still work on 8, and it _may_ work on 14, but you're on your own there.

Comment: I think you'll need the jdk for java 8, the jre isn't sufficient and java 14 is untested

Answer (score 1):

This is the known issue that still needs to be fixed.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14608

Answer (score 0):

You should read requirements Cassandra jdk version.I don`t think Cassandra works on higher version then Java 11.Reinstall your jdk problem will fix.

Answer (score -5):

Just Install Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA.
**Thank me later*

Comment: Thanks.  I installed 'IntelliJ IDEA', but I am still seeing this: # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=7476, tid=0x0000000000003440

I feel like it is some kind of permission issue thing.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Now, I get this message: Cassandra 4.0 requires either Java 8 (update 151 or newer) or Java 11 (or newer). Java 11.0.8 is not supported.
This is even more weird, because I just installed Java 11.  It seems like a tremendous effort for not a whole lot of payoff.